# Java: Assert that file serialization is complete?

Tags: java, filesystems, atomic

I am dealing with an object in Java that is very expensive to compute and several megabytes in size. In order to preserve it across application restarts, I want to serialize it into a `File`, and re-load that file on startup (if present).

The problem is that most file systems are not transactional. The file writing process can be interrupted by exceptions, JVM termination and/or power failure. What I absolutely need to assert is that if the file is used, the information within is **complete**. I can throw away the information and recalculate if needed, but reading and relying on incomplete data must be avoided.

My attempt would be to serialize and write a "seal" object at the end of the file, like a checksum for example. The presence of this object during deserialization guarantees that the serialization process was complete. If the seal object is absent during deserialization, I know that I cannot trust the data in the file as it might be incomplete. I am looking for an OS-independent solution, and I do not need to consider "attacks" that maliciously modify the contents of the serialized file.

**My question is:** Is the seal object approach outlined above *safe*, or are there still some corner cases where I can end up reading an incomplete file without noticing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write the file under a different, temporary name. Once the file is complete, delete any previous version of the file and rename the new file to the real name.

If program dies during write, you're just left with an incomplete temp file. The real file is still as before (or missing), so you'll never see an incomplete file to load.